# Connecting Sequelize to MySQL generating access denied error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect Sequelize to a local mySql instance. In testing I started out with Sqlite which works fine. Now I'm switching over to MySql getting a access denied error within my unit tests. This is a node.js project loading the sequelize module environment variables are being set using .env for local testing. 
Within the project I have a models directory which initializes the sequelize context:

**models/index.js**

```
let sequelize = {};

if (typeof process.env !== 'undefined' && process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.PASSWORD,
    { host: process.env.DB_HOST, dialect: process.env.MYSQLDIALECT, port: process.env.DB_PORT });
} else if(process.env !== 'undefined' &&  process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'development') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({dialect: process.env.DIALECT, storage: process.env.STORAGE});
}
```

**.env**

```
ENVIRONMENT=production

DB_NAME='MYRDSDataStore'
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER='sqlserviceuser'
DB_PASSWORD='password'
MYSQLDIALECT='mysql'

SQLITEDIALECT='sqlite'
STORAGE='db.sqlite'
```

Host is set to 127.0.0.1 but I have also tried localhost and received the same error.

**index.test.spec.js**

```
describe('Create Audit Table and insert error object', ()=>{
    it('Creates audit table and inserts record',()=>{

        let errorObject ={
            errorCode: '300',
            event: 'POST',
            userName: 'testUser',
            message: 'Error message from test'
        }
            util.AuditLogger(errorObject)
            .then(()=>{
                model.Audit.findAll({
                attributes: ['errorCode']
                }).then((data)=>{
                expect(data).to.have.lengthOf.at.least(1);
            });
        });
    });         
});
```

When I run my unit test I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'sqlserviceuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The user sqlserviceuser is a new user I created using sql workbench and granted the user dbo role (so they currently have full access)

From a terminal window I've tried the following command:

```
mysql -h localhost -u sqlserviceuser -p MYRDSDataStore
```

typing this I am then prompted for password which then allows me to login followed with the login message:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 29
Server version: 8.0.15 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Can anyone provide any suggestions or ideas as to why Sequelize would be failing or what I need to change to allow Sequelize to connect?

Thanks

Comment: DB_PASSWORD is actually set to password for the sqlserviceuser user?

Comment: yes I just setup a simple password for testing locally. I'd seen some posts where special characters caused issues so as a test I just used a basic character only password of 'password'  it won't be used in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.PASSWORD`

->

`sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD`

should be the problem here